# How to make ARIMA predict not the next observation but the n-th observation?

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I'm dealing with a time series forecasting problem, I'm quite new to ARIMA and time series so be patient with me ;). Actually my problem is that with "standard" ARIMA you are using a subset of the training set to predict the next observation in the series (if I'm not wrong...), what I want instead is:
a) to used a fixed amount of observation to predict the output, b) to predict not the next observation in the series but the one after a fixed number of observations (in practice i want to make a prediciton 24 hours ahead, so after 24 "positions" as I'm working with hourly data). Here is the code I'm using, how should I modify it?

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
train, test = array(load[:'2018']), array(load['2019':'2019'])
history = [x for x in train]
predictions = list()
# walk-forward validation
for t in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history, order=(1,1,0))
    model_fit = model.fit()
    output = model_fit.forecast()
    yhat = output[0]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    obs = test[t]
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%f, expected=%f, %f of %f' % (yhat, obs, t, len(test)))
# evaluate forecasts
rmse = sqrt(mean_squared_error(test, predictions))
print('Test RMSE: %.3f' % rmse)
```

Comment: https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_forecasting.html

Comment: Have you read the Harry Potter books? There was an episode when Harry was looking at the antidotes chapter. The whole text was crossed out by Snape with writing on markings "Just use bezoar". In time series prediction, if you do not want to go deeper with DL, just use prophet, It will save you a lot of time.